# Pushing container images to the Service Fabric image store

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-service-fabric, azure-container-registry

Instead of having to introduce a container registry (Azure Container Registry or another), is it possible to use the Service Fabric image store to host container images and then reference them from the Service Fabric container project's ServiceManifest inside `<ContainerHost><ImageName>...`? Documentation on both Service Fabric containers and the image store is limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Container images are not similar to Application packages.